# How to force macOS Music.app to sync to cloud?

Tags: music, catalina, beta-seed-program

I'm running Catalina 10.15.1 Beta and Music.app 10.1.33, and I have a large library of music from CDs. I can see but can't play this music from my iPhone since it's not available in the cloud.

In the Music -> Preferences I have *Library: Sync* ticked. In list view I see songs with a cloud with dashed outline. I've left the Music.app running for 24 hours and Activity Monitor shows 2.8MB of *Sent Bytes*.

How do I make Music.app wake up and send music to the cloud?

Comment: Did it work *before* you upgraded to Catalina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Music: File -> Library -> Update Cloud Library

Comment: Thanks - now I see an "Updating Cloud Library" progress notification in the bottom left, but data is being sent at ~10KB/s over my fiber connection. This will take a while...